# How to know the scroll position of a SemanticZoom?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

For an application in Windows 8 in C#/XAML, I am using a semantic zoom in a page. I would like to know the scroll position when I am scrolling in the page. With a scrollViewer it was easy :  I just had to recover the scrollViewer and use the property HorizontalOffset.

```
 var scrollView = element.FindName("itemGridScrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
 var scrollOffset = scrollView.HorizontalOffset;
```

But how can I achieve the same thing and access to the scroll informations in a semantic zoom ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could find the semantic zoom control you are interested in, access the visual tree, and then find the descendent scroll viewer to interrogate it's HorizontalOffset value.

The WinRT XAML Toolkit's [VisualTreeHelperExtensions](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/13620#228441) may help you out with this.